# Python3 Type Error on dict.pop

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.5

I'm trying to reflect a square of all permutation of a symmetric group.
The "coordinates" of the square are used as keys in a dictionary. The values
are now supposed to be reflected along the x-axis. But for some reason
the .pop() only wants to accept Integers? I thought it accepts any type that does not contain immutables and then raises a KeyError if a key is not in the dictionary. Here's my code:

```
def y_reflection(insquare):
    """Function that reflects a square against it's y axis:
                <----- reflection

                            --> x
    n   n-1 ... 2 1 |   1 2 ... n-1 n
    n-1 n-2 ... 1 n | | n 1 ... n-2 n-1
    ............... | v ................
    2   1   ... 4 3 | y 3 4 ... 1   2 
    1   n   ... 3 2 |   2 3 ... n   1"""

    for y in range (0, SQUARE_SIZE()):
        for x in range (0, SQUARE_SIZE()):
            insquare[(y,x)]=insquare.pop((y,(SQUARE_SIZE()-x)))
    return insquare

    insquare[(x,y)]=insquare.pop((x,(SQUARE_SIZE()-y)))
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: What exactly is `SQUARE_SIZE`? and `insquare`?

Comment: SQUARE_SIZE is n. The length of the axis. Insquare is the dictionary i described. It's simply the coordinates (x,y) as key and a value 0<x<n.

Answer (score 1):

Are you absolutely sure `insquare` is a `dict`? That's the error you'd get if `insquare` was a `list`.

Side-note: You're recalculating `SQUARE_SIZE()` a lot in this code; once for the outer `range` (not a problem), then `SQUARE_SIZE()` times for the inner `range`, then `SQUARE_SIZE() ** 2` times for the body of the inner loop. Even if `SQUARE_SIZE()` returns a constant value, the overhead to simply call a function is probably going to be a major factor in your runtime. If `SQUARE_SIZE()` has side-effects, you're invoking them a lot. To avoid lots of unnecessary `range` creation, `SQUARE_SIZE()` calls, and to unnest the loop, you might want to `import itertools` and change to something like this in your function:

```
sqsize = SQUARE_SIZE()
for y, x in itertools.product(range(sqsize), repeat=2):
    # I removed a bunch of unnecessary parens here as well
    insquare[y, x]=insquare.pop((y, sqsize - x))
return insquare
```

Comment: This is just my way of defining constants. Since I don't want the value get messed with but one can never be sure in python3 unless you use a function. But it just returns the same value the whole time.

Comment: And yes insquare was not a dict because I called it from the wrong place and did not notice.

Comment: @Elias: Except a function is not any safer. They could still just replace the function instead of the constant within the function. You're much better off not wrapping; it's the same protection (or lack thereof; Python assumes we're all adults and doesn't actually protect it, that's what the `CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES` name is for; to tell people not to change it), and it's going to be faster (still a global lookup, but no function call overhead).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code. The error is not inside that function. The error is where you are defining `insquare`. And From the looks of the error, you need to check whether you are passing a dictionary or not. I tried with the code below and it works perfect..

```
def y_reflection(insquare):
    """Function that reflects a square against it's y axis:
                <----- reflection

                            --> x
    n   n-1 ... 2 1 |   1 2 ... n-1 n
    n-1 n-2 ... 1 n | | n 1 ... n-2 n-1
    ............... | v ................
    2   1   ... 4 3 | y 3 4 ... 1   2 
    1   n   ... 3 2 |   2 3 ... n   1"""

    for y in range (0, 1):
        for x in range (0, 1):
            insquare[(y,x)]=insquare.pop((y,(1-x)))
    return insquare

    insquare[(x,y)]=insquare.pop((x,(1-y)))

d = {
        (0,0): 0,
        (0,1): 1,
        (1,0): 1,
        (1,1): 0
    }
print (y_reflection(d))
```

Test link - https://repl.it/B1kZ/1

Answer (score -1):

I think the error is in:

```
insquare[(x,y)]
```

This: `(x,y)` is a tuple.

Comment: That's not actually an error for a `dict`. A `dict` can be keyed on a `tuple` just fine. Doesn't even need the parens; `insquare[x, y]` works identically.

Comment: You're right, didn't read `insquare` is a dict, I thought it was a list.